# how to update gridview after collection has been set

Tags: gridview, microsoft-metro, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

I am trying to bind a `GridView` to a collection, and I want to update `GridView` after the collection has been set.

The reason I don't use `ObservableCollection` is that it will block UI if collection is large(more than 1000 items, and I want to show all items after all items has been added).
In metro style app, there is no BindingList class for C# use, so do I need to implement my own collection class? I tried to implement a class inherited `IList` and `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

I did something like this:

```
<GridView x:Name="ItemsGridView" ItemsSource="{Binding viewCollection}"/>

class MyBindingList<T> : IList<T>, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<Item> _viewCollection = new List<Item>();
    public List<Item> viewCollection 
    { get { return _viewCollection; } set { _viewCollection = value; } }
    public virtual event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaiseChanged()
    {
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("viewCollection"));
    }
}
MyBindingList<Item> list = new MyBindingList<Item>();
ItemsGridView.DataContext = list;
```

can someone give me a suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your code, your GridView is binding it's ItemsSource to viewCollection. The only thing you are missing why it is not notifying is the RaiseChanged() method.

```
  public List<Item> viewCollection 
{ get { return _viewCollection; } set { _viewCollection = value; RaiseChanged(); } }
```

One more thing, I won't suggest putting the string property on your RaiseChange method. It should be at least accepting a string property name and pass it in the PropertyChangedEventArgs.

An ideal property that notifies/updates the UI Controls in XAML would look like this

```
public List<Item> viewCollection 
    { get { return _viewCollection; } set { _viewCollection = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("viewCollection"); } }
```

So assuming your gonna set your viewCollection somewhere in your ViewModel. It should update the GridView.